# Can I install 12.04 using Wubi without an internet connection?

Tags: 12.04, installation

Do I need an active internet connection to install ubuntu 12.04 using wubi even after downloading the entire image file of the os.

Comment: yep that looks like a dup but it is about 11.10 maybe the questions need merged??

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to have the iso file.

Comment: @TrailRider i don't think it needs merging, as it should generally be the same.

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need an internet connection.
The following is from the [Wubi FAQ's](http://wubi.sourceforge.net/faq.php)

> Can I use an existing ISO/CD instead of letting Wubi download a new
> one?
>
> Yes, physical CDs will be detected automatically, pre-downloaded ISOs
> should be placed in the same folder as Wubi.exe. Please note tha Wubi
> 8.10 requires the Desktop 8.10 CD/ISO. The DVD and Altrenate CD/ISO will not work. You can find the 8.10 ISO here. If Wubi does not find
> an appropriate ISO/CD and/or if the ISO/CD is corrupted, it will
> automatically download a new ISO. It is recommended to let Wubi
> download the ISO for you.

The Wubi website has a lot of other info., you might want to take a look at it if you still have questions.

One thing I would recommend it running your Disk Check utility before installing Wubi.  One of the drawbacks of Wubi is that it is sensitive to a corrupted NTFS filesystem.  Doing a diskcheck will help prevent any problems.

**Note that Windows 8 is not compatible with Wubi**  To install on a Winodows 8 computer you will have to do a full install and it **must** be 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need to have the iso file. Extract your iso file in a directory. Keep the wubi file in the same directory. Now run wubi.exe

Comment: those steps didn't work my friend.